# I can't run 'appium -allow-cors'

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-behave, python-appium, appium-desktop

I want to run appium inspector using my browser, you can see what appium I use here https://inspector.appiumpro.com/ and to using this method, I must be run `appium -allow-cors` in terminal. But, the system display this:

[image]

How I can resolve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add " - " before " - allow" :
`appium --allow-cors`